# Android:Making a rest call using device name instead of ip address

Tags: java, android, spring, rest

I am creating a android application in which I use rest call to make connect with the controller class in the server.Here I am using the system ip address in the rest call url and its working fine.But the problem is I need to change the ip address in the url in each day if the system ip changes.I can't use the localhost because it will call the android sdk emulator in which the application is working instead of the system in which the controller and server resides.So i decides to use the machine name "myDevice3".But it results an exception when the rest makes call as below

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: myDevice3; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: myDevice3
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:456)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:404)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:202)
at com.app.saveitand.MainActivity.getListData(MainActivity.java:668)
at com.app.saveitand.MainActivity.loadExpense(MainActivity.java:742)
at com.app.saveitand.MainActivity$10.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:238)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: myDevice3
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:82)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:52)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:441)
```

Below is my rest call that I used with the ip address

```
String accList=restTemplate.getForObject("http://192.168.1.19:8080/SaveIt/stock/getCoaList/{parentId}", String.class, 10);
```

and its working fine,also there is no problem if I use the machine name in my swing desktop application rest call.If replace 192.168.1.19 with myDevice3 above exception will occur.So the exception occurs only when calling from the android emulator to my system.Please help me to solve this.

Comment: did you the url is working on browser?

Comment: yes..its working correctly on browser

Comment: @Exbury :also there is no problem if I use the machine name in my swing desktop application rest call

Answer (score 2):

Your browser and Swing apps do know your host name. And that's why they can connect to it. But Android(Dalvik) doesn't know it.

> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: myDevice3

Make sure that your Android phone knows that it s myDevice3.

Actually this is not right approach. Your phone should be client and connect to the server with some preferably static name/IP address. 
Yes, since it's Java, you can make server on the phone. There are even some applications to provide even web access to the phone. But common approach on these applications is to show pop up screen which says - connect to this particular IP address.

Comment: can you explain it in detail....How to make sure that my android phone knows this machine name?

Comment: Android is the same computer as anything else. All rules apply. What I do - open console and use standard unix tools to work with domain names, nslookup, ping and make sure that phone knows the other computer name. Here is some [article](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1458809) how to do so.

Answer (score -2):

use "http://10.0.2.2:8080/SaveIt/stock/getCoaList/{parentId}" instead of your url